# how to add type annotation to a destructed object literal with rest operator?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I destruct an object literal and use `spread/rest` operator.

How to add type annotation to the `rest` part?

I try to do this, but `tsc` throw an error.

```
const { x, y, ...rest }: {x: number, y: number, ...rest: any} = { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3, q: 4 };
```

Comment: First of all how will you access/use the const in the later part of the code?

Example it should be like 

const { x, y }: {x: number, y: number} = { x: 1, y: 2};//this cannot be used anywhere
const customVar1: {x: number, y: number} = { x: 1, y: 2};//this can be acccessed with customVar1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `...rest` part you can do the following:

```
const { x, y, ...rest }: { x: number, y: number, [key: string]: number } = { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3, q: 4 };
```

It basically means that it accepts any other keys as a string with number as the value.